# Start Transcript not capturing everything to log file

Tags: powershell, logging, neo4j, command

When I try to run the code below in powershell, everything goes smooth and I get the output that I want.

```
Start-Transcript -Path log.txt 
V:\neo4j\relate-data\dbmss\dbms-a5914a53-3b7d-42d0-a050-8bd6058e5e98\bin\neo4j-admin dump --database=neo4j --to=V:\neo4j\dumps
Stop-Transcript
```

[powershell screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o00Jg.png)

However, the log.txt file only has its header and the transcript itself is empty with no output? It's like start/stop transcript doesn't capture anything. It works though if i use ex. "dir" as command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `neo4j-admin` directly writes to the console, circumventing any attempts to redirect its output, so `Start-Transcript` can't do its job.

If the tool can't be changed, then there is a workaround. Recent Windows versions come with a *pseudo-console* (ConPTY) API, that provides a *virtual* console whose output can be captured programmatically. Using this API isn't trivial and seems a bit overkill for this task. Anyway, here is some [C# sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/tree/main/samples/ConPTY/MiniTerm) that could be ported to PowerShell or directly used as an assembly.

A **simpler way** is to use `mintty`, a console emulator that is able to log console output (it propably uses ConPTY internally). If you have Git for Windows installed, its path typically is `c:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe`. Otherwise you can get `mintty` [from GitHub](https://github.com/mintty/mintty).

Here is a simplified sample:

**WriteConsole.ps1:**

```sh
[Console]::WriteLine('foobar')
```

**Log all output of "WriteConsole.ps1", even direct writes to the console:**

```sh
& 'c:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe' -w hide -l log.txt powershell WriteConsole.ps1
```

See `mintty` [command-line parameters](https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html).